# Receive event before Windows enters standby or hibernate using Win32 API

Tags: windows, winapi, qt, hook, standby

I'm working on a small chat application written in C++/Qt. My users are complaining that the connection is not shut down gracefully when they are closing the laptop lid and the computer enters standby.

Is there a Win32 hook available that is called when Windows is about to enter standby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WM_POWERBROADCAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373247.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Reimplement [QCoreApplication::winEventFilter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#winEventFilter) in your application to handle Windows standby events.